# Django Rest framework - data between two serializers do not validate

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a API view in place where I first want to create a new user (already working) and second I want to return the new created user object using my UserSerializer (Not working).

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def user_create(request):
    exception_handler = UserUnavailable
    success_handler = UserCreated
    if request.method == 'POST':
        creation_serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            if creation_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                creation_serializer.save()
                user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=creation_serializer.instance.id)
                if user_serializer.is_valid():
                    return JsonResponse({"status_code": success_handler.status_code,
                                         "default_detail": success_handler.default_detail,
                                         "default_code": success_handler.default_code,
                                         "new_user": user_serializer,
                                         }, safe=False)
        except APIException:
            return JsonResponse({"status_code": exception_handler.status_code,
                                 "default_detail": exception_handler.default_detail,
                                 "default_code": exception_handler.default_code
                                 }, safe=False)
```

I can confirm that creation_serializer.instance.id contains the new users id.

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'user')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user')
```

I can also confirm that

```
if user_serializer.is_valid()
```

does not validate for some reason. Any ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you print `creation_serializer.data` ?

Comment: basically if i do creation_serializer.instance.id i get back the user ID but im not able to call UserSerializer like so user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=creation_serializer.instance.id)
It simply does not validate so I guess my issue is somewhere at the UserSerializer

Comment: @roo1989 I updated my whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize a serializer with user instance instead of

```
 user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=creation_serializer.instance.id)
```

You should write something like this:

```
user_serializer = UserSerializer(instance=creation_serializer.instance)
```

instead of

Also, you don't have to validate the object that has already been saved.
And create a response you should like this:

```
return JsonResponse({
    "status_code": success_handler.status_code,
    "default_detail": success_handler.default_detail,
    "default_code": success_handler.default_code,
    "new_user": user_serializer.data,
}, safe=False)
```

But using api_view is now a bad thing. It's much better to use ModelViewSet. You can use something like this:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return CreateUserSerializer
        return super().get_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        response_serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=serializer.instance)
        return Response(response_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

And I'm sorry, I haven't tested it, there might be typos.
You can read about ModelViewsets more here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: That was the trick, i wasn't aware that I most user instance=. Very useful.
Why are api_view is now a bad thing?

Comment: I would say they are actually deprecated for using to create ordinary API. They can be used for some special cases sometimes, although these cases are usually not related to models. It might be for example authorization API endpoint of something. For REST API ModelViewSet is the most convenient and powerful tool.

Comment: From my understand while still new to DRF function based views are more customizable or are at least intended to, please also see: https://dimgeo.com/posts/function-vs-class-based-views-in-django-rest/

Comment: You can do with ViewSet everything that you can do with APIView. So you use APIView when you don't need the functionality that ViewSet gives you.

Comment: And the standard REST API usually has the list, update, retrieve and create actions. If you don't need them then using ViewSet wouldn't be natural, although possible. so you are better off using use ApiView.

Comment: Okay :D thx for all the nice audience, really appreciate that. I guess that I was simply to long in charge with common views in Django so I guess I will stay with the "more complex" api_views.